# How to make process wait till AlertDialog event in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with an `AlertDialog`.

I would like my `AlertDialog` to return `true` if the user clicks on Positive button and false if he click on negative button. The function must block the program until the user click on a button.

My code :

```
    isSuspended = true;
public boolean alertDialog(){
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(input)
        .setPositiveButton("Authenticate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    if (isValid != 1) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ShowAlert.showAlertMessage(context, "title",
                            "Wrong Password!!!");
                    isSuspended = true;
                } else {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ShowAlert.showAlertMessage(context, "title",
                            "Correct Password!!!");
                    isSuspended = true;
                }
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            isSuspended=false;
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).show();
return isSuspended;
}
```